# Mongo field search by escaping the html tags from the value

Tags: mongodb

I've a mongo document like below,

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "car": "Honda",
  "description": "<b>Honda</b> vehicle is one of the ..."
}
```

When user search for the text "Honda vehicle" in description filter, then it'll not work with the direct text search. Because it has html tags in between. 
We have one other approach in mongo, $text-$search operation. But this operation requires the indexing of the text of the whole document, which is again costly.
Do we have any other alternate approach to filter such kind of document search operations?

Comment: I've two approaches to do this, but did not find the exact solution, Please find those below,
1) If the searched term is "Honda vehicle"By adding the AND operations between the given words "/^(?=.Honda)(?=.*vehicle).$/"   
2) Or by ignoring the html tags in the mongo documents.   
   For the second approach, I've the regex to find html tags, but i need to ignore the html tags and then find remaining matching words.

Comment: For second approach I've added another Question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56930710/need-regex-to-select-the-negative-pattern-selection-of-html-tags/56933049?noredirect=1#comment100408473_56933049

Comment: Also, another input, if mongo document have the below value, then also it should work.
```<a>KGI</a>ITT test```
Search word would be ```KGIITT test```