# Need regex to select the negative pattern selection of html tags

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need the regex pattern where it finds the text other than the html tags,

```
(<\s*[^>]*>)
```

And the text is

```
This is simple html text <span class='simple'>simple simple text text</span> text
```

Result should be

```
This is simple html text simple simple text text text
```

Please check the below link

https://regex101.com/r/cD8nG4/217

Answer (score 0):

In the example you gave, it is much easier to find the HTML tags with the regex you already have, and then replace the found strings with empty strings.

I have done that several times, and it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @virolino, but I need it for a different purpose. I can not modify the text. This regex will be used in mongo search operation.

Comment: The idea was to create a copy of the string, do the operations on the copy, keep what you need, throw away what you don't ;) Sorry for not being fully explicit from the beginning.

Comment: I need it for mongo search purpose, Posted another query here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56803588/mongo-field-search-by-escaping-the-html-tags-from-the-value